# Поддерживает ли github pages веб-приложение?

Tags: django, веб-программирование, nginx, github-pages

Хочу развернуть веб-приложение на django+nginx с помощью github pages. Возможно ли это или github pages поддерживает только статические сайты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github поддерживает эту технологию только с https://www.heroku.com/. Github pages может использовать только javascript для динамического отображения, серверную часть придеться делать как api

Comment: api нужно будет размещать, к примеру, на своём железе и к нему обращаться запросами?

Comment: Запросами, не обязтаельно на своем. Но лучше вам было все же посмотреть маны github